# laravel post request validation dont view error( validation Fail)

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5

i try to set rule to validate post request for laravel form to store data but if i set any validation rule ( either pass or fail ) it will show just blank empty page .
i using laravel 5 
**the form ( view ):**

```
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif    
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'RentalAgreementController@store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('dateOfAgreement', 'Date of Agreement', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'dateOfAgreement' , date('Y-m-d') , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'button']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(StoreAgreementPostRequest $request)
    {
        $agreement= new RentalAgreement(array(



            'dateOfAgreement'   =>  $request->dateOfAgreement,

        ));


        $agreement->save();
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Agreement successfully added! ');

        return view('home');
    }
```

**StoreAgreementPostRequest**

```
class StoreAgreementPostRequest extends Request {


public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    return [

       'premiseUse'=>'required|max:5'
    ];
}
```

}

just shows the black page but if i remove the rules its works . but for all other forms in this application validation way works ,( all other forms and controllers works perfectly).

Comment: Try with - `return View::make('home')`.

Comment: The problem isn't about the return, if use DD() even at the first line of the store() function won't return anything , but if just remove all the rules for validation then it works. Some how the validation is messed up!

Comment: use dd() in rules function to see what it shows & also where is your authorization logic? what's your authorization logic?

Comment: currently i don't use any authorization logic , and i set the value as true , also i used the dd() at the rules ,its works and shows the dd() value . but the validation won't work and just return empty page .